# Why does row reduction not change the dependence relation between columns?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I understand why it wouldn't change the dependence relation between rows, but that isn't intuitively clear for the columns (for me at least).

I realize that non-trivial solutions to the equation Ax = 0 implies a dependence relation among the columns of A, but what I don't understand is why elementary matrix operations wouldn't change the solution set.

Comment: In fact, row reduction _does_ change dependencies among the rows. In the RREF of a matrix, all of the zero rows—the ones that are linearly dependent—always come last.

Comment: See https://lem.ma/6wy and the subsequent lessons.

Answer (score 3):

There are many technical explanations that prove it, but don't explain why it's true.
What convinces me is to imagine **two columns where one is two times the other**.

```
Does swapping 1st and 3rd entries in each column change that relationship?
Obviously no.

Does multiplying 2nd entry by, say, 7 in each column change that relationship?
Obviously no.

Does adding a multiple of the 3rd entry to the 4th entry in each column change that relationship? 
Obviously no.
```

That gives me an insight that convinces me and I hope that you find it helpful.

For more, see https://lem.ma/6wy and the subsequent lessons.

Comment: This helps a lot, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

What you call "elementary matrix operations" amount to left-multiplication by an invertible matrix; therefore you are replacing $A$ with $BA$ for some invertible $B$.

But then $BAx=0$ iff $Ax=0$, so the solution set hasn't changed.

Comment: Oh that's also a great way of looking at it, forgot that elementary matrix operations is just left multiplying by an identity matrix. Thank you!